# Transitioning to ARC - release not raising error

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to move an existing non-ARC project to ARC. I have set the Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting flag in Build Settings to YES.

This has of course created a lot of errors about sending explicit release/autorelease messages. 
For errors that were in my code, I removed the explicit release messages, dealloc blocks etc.
For errors generated in third party libraries (like ASIHTTPRequest) I added the -fno-objc-arc flag for the required files in Build Phases - Compile Sources section.

However after I fixed all errors (and the project compiles successfully), I still have release statements in my code.

For example in the app delegate I use the following:

```
self.loginViewController       = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = self.loginViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[self.loginViewController release];
```

Now as I understand, this should have raised an error. But it doesn't. The app works as intended, but leaves me with questions on whether memory management is properly done in these files.

Neither the AppDelegate.m nor LoginViewController.m have the -fno-objc-arc flag set, so they should be defaulting to ARC.

Definitely I am doing something wrong. What should I double-check?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you use Edit->Refactor->Convert to Objective-C ARC? I find that's the easiest way to transition to ARC

Comment: I tried but it didn't work, because it still tries to convert my non-arc external libraries to ARC, although I have set the -fno-objc-arc flag for them. I don't want to mess with those libraries. Is there any way to specify which files will be refactored?

Comment: I found it. The targets actually expand and show you files that will and won't be converted.

Comment: I just finished refactoring and it did help a lot. I reviewed the changes and saved. However, it still didn't detect the explicit messages in some files like the delegate. XCode seems to ignore these files for ARC conversion for some reason. Very strange..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved this issue. I was using iRate library and in one of its headers it defines release and autorelease

```
#define release self
#define autorelease self
```

I deleted those lines and the problem was fixed. So if you ever encounter something like this, check if some 3rd party library has defined them.

Seriously, which decent programmer would define "release" and "autorelease" like this? Amazing...

Comment: Actually very intelligent ones.  I'll bet my two cents that they did it for backwards compatability with non-ARC.  They must have done a conditional define and made release do nothing under arc.  Smart.  You should use it.

Comment: I wouldn't mind if the scope of this define stayed in their own code, but it effects my code too. So if I import iRate.h in an ARC project, in a class that has ARC specifically disabled, the define extends to my class and breaks my release statements, right? I'm not trying to be clever, that is exactly the case in an app I have on the App Store right now.